# Make a button have brackets on each side with CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I would love to figure out how to create a button with CSS that has 'brackets' on each side. To clarify, not just the brackets you get by typing them, but larger brackets, like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an approach where you can edit size thickness and length of the brackets involving box-shadow

```css
.brackets {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px black;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  }
.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: none;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div class="brackets">
  <button class="button">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Rudi, thanks so much for the response. This is almost exactly what I need. Forgive me if this is a naive question, but is there anyway to determine the size of the .bracket DIV by the text contained within the .button? This would allow me to apply this solution to any button, no matter how much text is in it. I read a few others threads concerning sizing the parent DIV based on contents, but wasn't able to make any progress with it. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `before` and `after` pseudo selectors with the `content` attribute:

```css
button {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
button::before {
  content: "[ ";
  font-size: 1.5em;
    
}
button::after {
  content: " ]";
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

button.bigtext {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<button>Some Text</button>
<br />
<button class="bigtext">Some Text</button>
```

Comment: +1 for the use of the pseudo class selectors, but I think the OP was looking for something with larger-sized brackets, per his post.  I think he'll run into some vertical alignment issues with this solution if he just tries to increase the bracket size, but nothing that can't be overcome.

Comment: @scarabaeus, thanks for the comment! I changed the code a bit with an example for larger font :)

Comment: No problem!  I think he's looking for larger brackets relative to the text...  But that's just a guess. Don't waste your time fixing it on my account.  Maybe your proposed solution is acceptable to the OP as-is.  (Although, I would be curious to see your solve it.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I haven't yet had a chance to try it out, but will be in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to achieve this.

First and easiest: Create a button background in Photoshop or whatever and use that as your button background.

Second: Type the brackets and button text you want and then style the  separate pieces.

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <p><span class="large">[</span>Button<span class="large">]</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.large {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Those are they straight forward ways I can think of that are really quick and easy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I was hoping for a purely CSS solution to give me maximum control over thickness/size etc. I'll be trying out the solutions listed in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow the question.  Just put a bracket around it.  Example below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><title>Title Here </title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<center>Your Title</center>
<br>
Some Text Data Here 
<style type="text/css">
#modernbricksmenu { padding: 0; width: 100%; background: transparent; voice-family: ''}''; voice-family: inherit; } 
#modernbricksmenu ul { font: bold 11px Arial; margin:0; margin-left: 40px; /*margin between first menu item and left browser edge*/ padding: 0; list-style: none; } 
#modernbricksmenu li {   display: inline; margin: 0 2px 0 0; padding: 0; text-transform:uppercase; }
#modernbricksmenu a { float: left; display: block; color: white; margin: 0 1px 0 0; /*Margin between each menu item*/ 
padding: 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px; background-color: black; /*Default menu color*/ border-bottom: 1px solid white; } 
#modernbricksmenu a:hover { background-color: gray; /*Menu hover bgcolor*/ } 
#modernbricksmenu #current a { /*currently selected tab*/ background-color: #D25A0B; /*Brown color theme*/  border-color: #D25A0B; /*Brown color theme*/  } 
#modernbricksmenuline { clear: both; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 5px; line-height: 5px; background: #D25A0B; /*Brown color theme*/  } 
#myform { /*CSS for sample search box. Remove if desired */ float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
#myform .textinput { width: 190px; border: 1px solid gray; } 
#myform .submit { font: bold 11px Verdana; height: 22px; background-color: lightyellow; } </style> 
<div id="modernbricksmenu"> <ul> <li style="margin-left: 1px">
<a href="page.com" title="SomePage">   Home</a></li> <li>                         
<a href="page.com" title="SomeOther">  New</a></li> <li id="current">            
<a href="page.com" title="AnotherOne"> Revised</a></li> <li>                         
<a href="page.com" title="StilMore">   [Tools]</a></li> <li>                         
<a href="page.com" title="GoAway">     Forums</a></li> </ul>
</div>
<div id="modernbricksmenuline">&nbsp;</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I haven't yet had a chance to try out your solution, but using the bracket characters doesn't seem like it will give me as much control over the size/shape of the brackets. However, I will be trying out all the solutions given in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to change my template, so I've come up with a pure CSS solution.
It'll also work with every background.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 8px 24px; 
}

.btn::before,
.btn::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  content: "";
}

.btn::before {
  left: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

.btn::after {
  right: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary">Buttton</a>
```